How can I stop writeRaster from changing the extent of processed raster data?
I need to align raster data from several files. To do this I am using a for loop as shown below. As a check I print the extent of each of the rasters before calling writeRaster() to write the aligned data to new .tiff files.
Immediately after this I use a new for loop to read the newly written files and check their extent as I keep running into the "Error: [rast] extents do not match" when trying to load the data for further processing. From the output it is clear that the extents are different so the error must come in when calling the writeRaster() method.
What can I do to prevent this from happening?
wd <- getwd()
outpath <- paste0(wd, "/new_folder/")
dir.create(outpath)
rf <- list.files(pattern = '.tiff$')
vf <- list.files(pattern = '.gpkg')
outfiles <- paste0(outpath, rf)
ref_res <- rast("heritage0001_vigour_2023-10-23_2023-12-12.tiff")
ref_ext <- ext(rast("heritage0001_yield_2023-11-06_2023-11-10.tiff"))
m <- vect(vf)
for (i in 1:length(rf)) {
   r <- rast(rf[i])
   rr <- resample(r, ref_res, method = "bilinear")
   rc <- mask(rr, m)
   print(ext(rc))
   rw <- writeRaster(rc, outfiles[i], overwrite = TRUE)
   #print(outfiles[i])
 }

# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

rf2 <- list.files(path = "./new_folder", pattern = '.tiff$')
  for (i in 1:length(rf2)) {
    print(ext(rast(rf2[i])))
  }

# SpatExtent : 29.0653074354221, 29.0747286636125, -27.9793979274217, -27.9667846383642 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0653074354221, 29.0747286636125, -27.9793979274217, -27.9667846383642 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0653074354221, 29.0747286636125, -27.9793979274217, -27.9667846383642 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0595044907393, 29.0795844585379, -27.9793947979182, -27.9559820553812 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# SpatExtent : 29.0653338559072, 29.0747209013373, -27.9793894969512, -27.9668433496937 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

t <- rast(rf2)
# Error: [rast] extents do not match


it looks like in this example the fourth one is different from the other four. Can you simplify your processing to just work with this fourth one and see what happens? Assuming the two loops are in the same order, just try for(i in 4) and see if the output tiff has the right extent..

Please do not put non-code (ie., console carriage returns characters, error messages) in code blocks.

Actually it looks like the fourth one is the only one that is correct. The others all have a different extent reported from the raster object that is written compared to the one that is read. I can't see anything in writeRaster that would do this, are you trying and failing to overwrite existing rasters?

Thank you Jeffry, sorry about that. I will make sure that i post the code in a clean manner in the future. I'm still quite new to this. I should probable also remove the question as the fault was not with writeRaster(). The files were getting written correctly. There is however an error in my list.files() call. I need to add the following argument "full.names = TRUE"

I have managed to figure out what i did wrong. The fault is not with the writeRaster() function. It is with the implementation of the list.files() call afterwards. That function should have the following argument added in order to ensure it does not select the files from the parent directory.
list.files(path = "./path_to_directory/", pattern = '.tiff$', full.names = TRUE)
I hope this assists others that run in to similar issues.
